# Where are iis7/iis10 application pool restart/shutdown logs? How can I find it?

Tags: logging, shutdown, application-pool

According to: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johan/2008/02/18/monitoring-application-pool-and-application-restarts/

I should change root web.config by adding to healthMonitoring.rules:

```
<add name="Application Lifetime Events Default" eventName="Application Lifetime Events"
provider="EventLogProvider" profile="Default" minInstances="1"
maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:01:00" custom="" />
```

I do not know where I can find this log and how to find it? I should use eventview?

Sorry for My English.

Answer (score 0):

After re-search I found this info by 'eventvwr'. In My case information about application pool restart was logged on level 'information' and event source was 'WAS' and it was 'Idle time limit' for app pool.